# Flash 8 vs. CSS3 Matrix Transform (affine)

Tags: css, transform, flash-8

I have a flash 8 application that consumes strings representing flash's Matrix(a,b,c,d,tx,ty) for affine transformations. I would like to use the same transformation matrix strings in CSS:

```
transform:matrix(a,b,c,d,tx,ty);
-ms-transform:matrix(a,b,c,d,tx,ty); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:matrix(a,b,c,d,tx,ty); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:matrix(a,b,c,d,tx,ty); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:matrix(a,b,c,d,tx,ty); /* Opera */
```

The results are very close but I am seeing odd differences, mainly in the tx and ty. An image transformed in Flash8 and CSS3 with identical Matrix parameters result in slightly differnet positioning. That is, the CSS object might appear a bit high or a bit to the right.

Is there a difference in the algorithm Flash8 uses vs. CSS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! The algorithms are identical, we were not using the right t-matrix data!!!

Comment: So what was the right data? Your question seems too localized otherwise :/ (God I miss Flash 8 and all its Macromedia-ness)

Comment: Our app specifies the matrix parameters for various parts of a car - scale, skew, translation, rotation. We had the right matrix for the wrong part - when we corrected the matrix both flash and our CSS3 experiment worked identically.